# Makefile - Export with regular expression

Tags: c, github, makefile, git-submodules

I am working on C project XYZ. This project is dependent on another C project ABC. So, to do make for XYZ we have to do make for ABC first. For this I have first added ABC as submodule to XYZ like below

```
git submodule add git@github.com:username/ABC.git  
git add .gitmodules  
git add ABC  
git push
```

So to build my XYZ project, ABC needs to be build first. So my makefile in XYZ project is like below:

```
ifndef PRT  
PRT=ABC  
export PRT  
endif

.PHONY: project_ project_clean project_check clean XYZ_package package check

project_ project_clean project_check:  
        @echo "(MAKE) -C src -s $(@:project_%=%)"  
        @$(MAKE) -C src -s $(@:project_%=%)  

clean: project_clean

XYZ_package package:  
        ./scripts/package.sh
check: project_check
```

This is working locally, but when I try to build it **in github, it fails**. Because in github, the folder is `XYZ @ 324354`. It shows error like below:

```
(MAKE) -C src -s   
make: *** ABC: No such file or directory.  Stop.  
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2  
make: *** [project_] Error 2
```

How to make `PRT variable` set to correct path so that it will point to correct folder always.

Comment: so this variable represents the folder you're building into? I think you can clarify a bit more...

Comment: Please show the exact command you executed to get this error.  Also you should remove all `@` prefixes from your makefile recipes, at least until it works properly.  Better would be to never have them and use something like http://make.mad-scientist.net/managing-recipe-echoing/ to control it.

Comment: The "problem" here is in the makefile that's in the `src` subdirectory, which you haven't shown us at all so there's no way to know what's going on.  Your invocation of the sub-make in the `src` subdirectory works, then that invocation prints this error.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you're asking (it would be a lot simpler if you provided a specific example showing real directory names etc.)

But I think, based on your comment, something like this could work:

```
ifndef PRT
PRT := $(wildcard sub-project*)
endif
export PRT
```

Comment: It still gives the same error. Please check my edited version of the question